# Show all open buffers in Emacs

Tags: emacs, elisp, emacs23

In emacs, is there an M-x command or key combo to render all current open buffers into different windows? 
For clarity, let's suppose I have four open buffers, and I am only seeing one currently being displayed, and I would like in one step to show each buffer in one quadrant.

Comment: 4 buffers?  My Emacs has 188 buffers open right now (although only 154 are actually visiting files).

Comment: cjm do you have all these buffers split into different parts of the screen?

Comment: Obviously not, they wouldn't fit.  I only have a few at a time actually displayed (often only 1).

Comment: Sometimes I have ~20 buffers, a terminal, tetris and something else open, but I always close them when I'm done with that project. From time to time, I split them using 'C-x 3' and 'C-x 2'. By the way, @cjm, more buffers will use much more RAM, right?

Comment: @user996056: Much more RAM? Depends on how big the buffers are.  My Emacs process right now is 59MB, making it the second largest app currently open, but hardly a problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will be able to start with the following code if there is not an already-known way to do it:

```lisp
(defun buffer-in-window-list ()
  (let (buffers)
    (walk-windows (lambda (window) (push (window-buffer window) buffers)) t t)
    buffers))

(defun display-all-buffers ()
  (interactive)
  (let (buffers-in-window (buffer-in-window-list))
    (dolist (buffer (buffer-list))
      (when (and (not (string-match "\\`[[:space:]]*\\*" (buffer-name buffer)))
                 (not (memq buffer buffers-in-window)))
        (set-window-buffer (split-window (get-largest-window)) buffer)))
    (balance-windows)))
```

The `display-all-buffers` command opens a new window for each buffer that is not currently displayed anywhere (including other frames). For usability, it ignores buffers whose names start with `*` (optionally, prefixed with whitespace characters) because they are usually for internal use only.

Note that Emacs does not allow a user to make too small a window. So, when there are too many buffers to display, the command will display as many buffers as possible in order of most recent display or selection and signal an error.

Answer (score 4):

I recommend ibuffer. M-x ibuffer is probably what you want. Here's my ibuffer configuration:

```
;; *Messages* is so annoying. Also, I really like ibuffer
(require 'ibuf-ext)
(add-to-list 'ibuffer-never-show-predicates "^\\*Messages")
(add-to-list 'ibuffer-never-show-predicates "^\\*Completions")
(global-set-key (kbd "C-b") 'ibuffer)
(kill-buffer "*scratch*")
('ibuffer)
(switch-to-buffer "*Ibuffer*")
```

Comment: Thanks user996056, I didn't know about ibuffer, and this config is good to have!

Comment: Doesn't work for me, says that `ibuffer is not defined`

Comment: @yegor256 That's weird because ibuffer is a built-in function. You'll probably have to open an issue on the emacs stack exchange about that. Or  try and reinstall?